# How much data can I store in a lookup table on App Engine without running into performance problems?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, scalability, lookup-tables

I currently have ~30,000 entities (about 10 MB) that I am storing in the datastore. The data never changes, except when I update it as an administrator. To avoid the hassle of using the bulkloader, I am toying with the idea of just storing all of this data in a python dict.

Has anyone tried this? How much data can I get away with storing in a dict on App Engine without extremely bad spin-up times for new instances? Are there other downsides to storing 30k objects in memory on App Engine?

Comment: Do they all need to be in memory at once, or can you use memcache on just the entities that are requested?

Comment: In each request, only a handful will be used. The main purpose of keeping them in a python dict would be for the convenience of updating them through an app update rather than a bulkloader upload. What I'm looking for with this question is the downsides of this approach and (roughly) the magnitude of those downsides. I expect that spin-up time will be worse, but is it going to be 2 seconds rather than 1 second? I could live with that. On the other hand, if it's a minute, perhaps not.

Comment: Depends on the data.  Try it out and see what happens.

Comment: Alternately store it as a pickle in gcs, and the just load it into memory on instance startup, or when it get's some web request telling it to invalidate it's cache. Then you don't have to do an application update.

Answer (score 0):

Holding all static data in memory is a great idea to improve performance. Non surprisingly, how much data you can you in memory depends on how much memory you have.

App Engine allows you to choose how much memory to put on your instances, so the limit will depend on your choice. For now the default is 128MB, configurable up to 1024MB.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings